# Как добавить option в select

Tags: jquery, ajax

Получаю данные в json. Пытаюсь их пропустить через each. Вроде все получилось, но фильтры все в 1 option добавляются а не каждые в свой.

```
 $('#filter_template').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '{{ url('admin/api/filters') }}',
        data: {
            cat_id: $('#filter_template').val()
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(jsondata){
            $.each(jsondata, function(index, filter_group) {
                var li = "<li>" + filter_group.name + "</li>";
                var select = "<select name=\"filters[]\" id=\"filters\">" + "</select>";
                var group = $('#results').append(li + select);
                $.each(filter_group.filters, function(index, filter){
                    group.find($('select')).append($("<option></option>", {value: filter.id, text: filter.name}));
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Получается так, что все filter.name добавляются в первый селект, а я хочу что бы они добавлялись каждый к своей группе фильтров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в том как вы получаете Select для добавления option

```
group.find($('select')).append($("<option></option>", {value: filter.id, text: filter.name}));
```

`group.find($('select'))` - находит первый Select

Вам нужно присваивать каждому select отдельный id и добавлять option так `group.find($('#select1')).append($("<option></option>", {value: filter.id, text: filter.name}));`

Comment: как назначить ид? Вот так не выходи `var select = "<select name=\"filters[]\" class=\"push-5 push-5-t\" id=\"filters" + group.id + "\">" + "</select>";`  и ищу  ` group.find($('#filters'+filter_group.id)).append($("<option></option>", {value: filter.id, text: filter.name}))` Ну оно и понятно, что filter_group` уже нет. Как по другому?

Comment: Конечно не выходит. Но не потому, что filter_group уже нет, оно не куда не пропало из этой области видимости. А потому, что вы пытаетесь откуда то взять group.id в начале.

Comment: Огромнейшее вам спасибо. И дай бог здоровья) 2 дня мучился из-за своей не внимательности)

Comment: Да не за что. Удачи)